# Bootstrap selectbox not working properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu

I have implemented bootstrap selectbox on my site and they are working fine on all browsers except chrome. On chrome it shows the select box properly but I am not able to select options ( value is not changing ). Its not even showing any error ( in console logs ). I checked with ordinary selectbox and they are working fine on same system but bootstrap selectbox is not allowing me to change the value.

How should I debug this and fix it ?

this is the code i have used to add bootstrap selectbox

```
$('#booking-field-select-time, #client-booking-field-select-time').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Comment: write the code for the part which you think have problem.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: $('#booking-field-select-time, #client-booking-field-select-time').selectpicker('refresh');

Comment: with above code its working properly on all other browsers.